# Ajax Button Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable a button after a user did rate a certain post, using Ajax. The goal is to avoid an unnessary increase of the votes for this post.
 Here is code,help me

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // show the spinner
    $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");

    //fadeout the vote-count 
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");

    //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "votes.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
                //fadein the vote count
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
                //remove the spinner
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();

            }
        });
    });


}); 
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using a html button, then disable it by answer below from @gopi1410

Comment: else show some of your html code too besides the js used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a single click to your `a` tag:

See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/VcfSh/)

```
$(function(){
    //click only once
    $("a.vote_up").one("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('p').append('clicked ');
    });
});
```

**Note:**

Added `e.preventDefault();` to disallow the browser from following the href attribute. ([read here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/))

Answer (score 0):

I would simply hide the **anchor tag** after posting it by using the hide method. Another thing you have to do is to user the `preventDefault` method to prevent the default behaviour of the link.

```
 $(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var item=$(this);
    the_id = item.attr('id');
    $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id="+the_id,
            url: "votes.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);                 
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();                   
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
                item.hide();  // hide the link

            }
        });
    });    

});
```

If you want to keep the link as it is without hiding it, you can do it in this way. when you  get the success response from the ajax call, set one attribute value of the link to "done" or some value. Whenever the link is being clicked, first check the value is set or not. If yes. don't do ajax again. something like this.

```
 $(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var item=$(this);
      if(item.attr("status")!="voted")
      {
         the_id = item.attr('id');
         $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");
         $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");

          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: "action=vote_up&id="+the_id,
             url: "votes.php",
             success: function(msg)
             {
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);                 
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();                   
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
                item.attr("status","voted");
                item.addClass("disabledLook"); //apply a css class to make the link look like disabled    
             }
           });
       }
    });        
});
```

Comment: I try this to disable the button but it is still not working,"item.hide();" is also not working,when i refresh the page button appears again,i dont want this $("#a.vote_up").attr("disabled", false);

Comment: actually i am making a voting system,users can vote a certain post once in day,not more than that.so i used ajax and jquery to refresh the certain part of webpage,but when i refresh the page,vote button appears again?????

Comment: @user1393966: There is nothing wrong with your code then. That is how HTTP works. Rememebe HTTP is stateless. When you refresh the page, your browser sends a new request to the server and server responds back like how it does for the first time. Solution to avoid this is to keep data in cookie, localstorage(if html5),hide button if data is already in table (for registered users), Session varaible (state remains untill the session ends) etc..

Comment: then where to put the code,if user had already voted for a particular post,

Comment: @user1393966 :As i mentioned in my previous comment, you need to use either cookies/session/database depending on your scenario

Comment: You will also want to do some server side checking since people can by pass the disable fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/8ekRD/) to disable a button by javascript.

If you want it to remain disabled even after refreshing the page, you have to store somewhere that the user has cast his vote either by using html5 storage, cookies or session variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simple unbind action from `a` after sending request with one line of code:

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    // you ajax request here
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```